# When I printed the address of returned array in main func, Same memory location is printing twice even though I called function once to print address

Tags: arrays, c, function

```
int *bubble_sort(int[]);
 void main()
{
    int arr[10]={ 10, 9, 7, 101, 23, 44, 12, 78, 34, 23};
    printf("\n%d\n",bubble_sort(arr));
    int *p = bubble_sort(arr);
    printf("\nprinting sorted elements ...\n");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       printf("%d\n",p[i]);
    return 0; 
}
 int *bubble_sort(int a[])
{
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
         {
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
               {
                 temp = a[j];
                 a[j]=a[j+1];              
              a[j+1] = temp;
               }
          }
       }
    printf("%d",a);
    return a;
}
```

In the main function, I called the bubble sort which returns the base location of the array and printed that location. Even though it is pointing to the same memory location still printing the address twice. Please share your thoughts on this behavior.
The line to be analyzed "printf("\n%d\n",bubble_sort(arr));"

Comment: You print the address in the body of `bubble_sort`.  Calling `bubble_sort` as the argument to `printf` prints it once, and the `printf` prints it a second time.

Answer (score 1):

The address you print outside the function and inside the function will be the same. It's the address of the first element in `arr`, `&arr[0]` - and it will be printed three times in your program.

- You call `bubble_sort` twice, so the print inside `bubble_sort` will be printed twice.
- You print the address one time in `main`.
- So: 2 + 1 = 3

Some issues:

- `void main()` is not a valid `main` signature. It should return `int`
- `for(j=0;j<10;j++)` and `a[j+1]` makes your program have *undefined behavior*. You access `a` out of bounds when `j` is `9`
- `printf("%d", a);` and `printf("\n%d\n",bubble_sort(arr));` also makes your program have *undefined behavior* since you supply an address to the `%d` conversion specifier. Use `%p` to print the value of pointers.
- You loop more than necessary. After a value has "bubbled up", you don't need to check it again and again.
- Calling `bubble_sort` twice is unnecessary.

Suggested changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* bubble_sort(int a[], int length) {   /* take the length as an argument */
    int i, j, temp;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {         /* 0 up to 9 */
        for(j = length - 1; j > i; j--) { /* 9 down to i + 1 */
            if(a[j] < a[j - 1]) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("in bubble_sort: %p\n", (void*)a);     /* %p to print pointers */
    return a;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[10] = {10, 9, 7, 101, 23, 44, 12, 78, 34, 23};
    int* p = bubble_sort(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])); /* call once only */
    printf("in main:        %p\n", (void*)p);     /* %p to print pointers */
    printf("\nprinting sorted elements ...\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
in bubble_sort: 0x7ffc91ff68d0
in main:        0x7ffc91ff68d0

printing sorted elements ...
7
9
10
12
23
23
34
44
78
101
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo still your edited program is running one additional time in the outer loop so we can make it length - 1 to make it optimal. but still didn't get the exact reason behind it
0061FEA0,
0061FEA0

printing sorted elements ...
7
9
10
12
23
23
34
44
78
101
Got the answer but not clear about the functionality.

Comment: @pranaynallapaneni  - in printf statement you are calling the bubble_sort() which internally printing the array address - to cross check, add few characters in each printf statement, you will know why, much better

Comment: @pranaynallapaneni Good catch about the loop. Yes it's the same address. It's the address of the first element in `arr` (`&arr[0]`) as I just added to the answer.

Comment: @Sudhee Thanks you drawn to the exact point. If I print the pointer after assigning function to pointer. address is printing twice. int *p = bubble_sort(arr);
    printf("\n%p\n",p); if I use the bubble_sort(arr) above pointer declaration it is printing thrice. can you please explain this behaviour.

Comment: @ikegami: the special meaning `()` only applies in function declarations that are not definitions.  In a function definition `int main() {`... and `int main(void) {`... are identical.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - I get wrong answer for bubble sort - Just run as is - o/p is  10
7
9
12
23
23
34
44
78
101

Comment: @Chris Dodd, ah ok. This was not what I was told.

Comment: @Sudhee Yeah, it was a mistake to remove one loop in the outer loop. I fixed that.

Comment: @pranaynallapaneni I've updated my answer. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Thanks - i was trying to understand what is the benefit of running second loop 9 down to i+1 instead of normal 0 to len-i-1.

Comment: @Sudhee Looping up or down doesn't matter. I just find `for(j = length - 1; j > i; j--)` easier to read than `for(j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++)`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer why 2 times (Actually it is 3 times) address is printed

From the code below

```
int arr[10]={ 10, 9, 7, 101, 23, 44, 12, 78, 34, 23};
printf("\n%d\n",bubble_sort(arr));
int *p = bubble_sort(arr);
```

There is 2 times function call to `bubble_sort()` - Note you are printing the address of array in `bubble_sort()` function too. All three address is pointing to start of the arr[].

Hence the 3 times address printing coming from

1. 2 times from line`printf("\n%d\n",bubble_sort(arr));`  ( one from the `printf` and another from the `bubble_sort(arr)` fucntion call)
2. 1 time from  `int *p = bubble_sort(arr);`

Comment: Thanks for making it clear, I got your point. I assumed the same but return arr confused me. printf is independent so it can print it address.

Comment: If we print the address of pointer we are getting two addresses which are address of pointer and address of arr.